# what is the idiomatic way to update *part* of a memory element in FIRRTL? this comes up when updating one entry of a line in a cache

Tags: chisel, firrtl

Writing a register file in FIRRTL is straightforward: make a memory of machine words and read/write them.

However, when writing a cache, it is different: you typically have a cache line and when writing, only want to update *part* of the line, a single element of a line of the cache.

What is the idiomatic way to do this in FIRRTL?  (And please do not point me at the Rocket implementation in Chisel as I find Chisel to be completely unreadable.)

I can think of at least two ways to do it:

(1) make the memory contain a Vector or Bundle and then select that member of the memory element, something like this:

```
cmem mem1 : {x:SInt<64>,y:SInt<64>}[4]
infer mport temp_x_mem1 = mem1[i].x, clock
temp_x_mem1 <= foo
```

(2) do some sort of read-modify-write, something like this:

```
cmem mem1 : {x:SInt<64>,y:SInt<64>}[4]
infer mport temp_x_mem1 = mem1[i], clock
bar <= temp_x_mem1
bar.x <= foo
infer mport temp_x_mem1_B = mem1[i], clock
temp_x_mem1_B <= bar
```

I am generating my FIRRTL from another format and I did not plan for this, so when I generate a memory, the only straightforward way is to read or write an entire memory element, not part of one.  Therefore way (1) is difficult, but way (2) is straightforward.  Would some layer of the FIRRTL optimizer or a subsequent Verilog optimizer make way (2) work as efficiently as way (1) if all of the code occurred in the same module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use a FIRRTL memory construct (`mem`) and avoid CHIRRTL entirely (`cmem`/`smem`).  The former gives you an explicit mask port on the memory.  This then enables you to describe a masked write which is exactly what you want.  FIRRTL memory constructs have no Chisel API, but it sounds like you are using something else so this may not be an issue.

Approach (1) will not work as you can't use a part select to describe a memory port.  (`infer mport temp_x_mem1 = mem1[i].x, clock` is illegal CHIRRTL.)  Approach (2) will work, but you pay a cycle penalty to do it.

There is a third, idiomatic approach that involves describing the memory in such a way that a FIRRTL compiler will *infer* the mask.  This is done by guarding the write behind a `when` statement which contains the enable:

```scala
circuit Foo:
  module Foo:
    input clock: Clock
    input i: UInt<2>
    input mask: {x: UInt<1>, y: UInt<1>}
    input data: {x: SInt<64>, y: SInt<64>}

    cmem mem1 : {x:SInt<64>,y:SInt<64>}[4]

    infer mport temp_x_mem1 = mem1[i], clock

    when eq(mask.x, UInt<1>(1)):
      temp_x_mem1.x <= data.x
    when eq(mask.y, UInt<1>(1)):
      temp_x_mem1.y <= data.y
```

Either the [Scala-based FIRRTL Compiler](https://github.com/chipsalliance/firrtl) or the [MLIR-based FIRRTL Compiler](https://github.com/llvm/circt) will infer the when conditions as the mask.

MLIR-based FIRRTL Compiler output:

```
circuit Foo :
  module Foo :
    input clock : Clock
    input i : UInt<2>
    input mask : { x : UInt<1>, y : UInt<1> }
    input data : { x : SInt<64>, y : SInt<64> }

    mem mem1 : 
      data-type => { x : SInt<64>, y : SInt<64> }
      depth => 4
      read-latency => 0
      write-latency => 1
      writer => temp_x_mem1
      read-under-write => undefined
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.addr is invalid 
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.en <= UInt<1>(0) 
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.clk is invalid 
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.data is invalid 
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.mask is invalid 
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.addr <= i
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.en <= UInt<1>(1) 
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.clk <= clock 
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.mask.x <= UInt<1>(0) 
    mem1.temp_x_mem1.mask.y <= UInt<1>(0) 
    when eq(mask.x, UInt<1>(1)) : 
      mem1.temp_x_mem1.mask.x <= UInt<1>(1) 
      mem1.temp_x_mem1.data.x <= data.x 
    when eq(mask.y, UInt<1>(1)) : 
      mem1.temp_x_mem1.mask.y <= UInt<1>(1) 
      mem1.temp_x_mem1.data.y <= data.y
```

Comment: Suppose I wanted to emit the write to the mport using nested muxes instead of when statements; can I do it like this?: temp_x_mem1.x <= mux(write_x, data.x, temp_x_mem1.x), where the "else" part of the mux means just "do nothing". Would this work, or would this make temp_x_mem1 into a read-write port when I just want it to be a write port?

Comment: I don't think It would work due to the memory inference algorithms (heuristics), that got enshrined in the Scala-based FIRRTL Compiler, being defined in terms of `when` statements.

Comment: I have confirmed that using a mux to write a memory and reading the same mport as the default when no change is wanted results in a readwriter mport; in contrast, as you suggest, using a when-tree and not writing at all when no write is wanted results in a writer mport.  Thank you for your help.